# What is convention on where to install cross-platform libraries?

Tags: libraries, directory-structure, shared-library, cross-compilation

What is the prevailing (or correct) convention on where to install cross-platform libraries?

E.g. `libfoo.so.1.0.0` compiled for the host might typically be located at `/usr/local/lib/`. If I also had to install `libfoo` for a non-host architecture, e.g. ARM, where should it go?

Some reading leads me to `/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/`, but other reading leads me to `/usr/local/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/`.

I've recently started learning about the "configure; make; make install" recipe; `configure` takes a `--prefix` argument, so it ends up following the latter convention. Does that mean that is the prevailing/correct convention? OTOH, people have claimed that the former is the "debian convention," but I'm having a hard time finding evidence to back that up.

Comment: Read [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and documentation of [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to you as long as it's a separate directory not used by your system.

You can even use something like `/opt/arm64` or even `/arm64`.